# Cadaster or cadastre in an American journal?

Tags: american-english, spelling

I am going to submit an article in an American journal. I use the spelling "cadaster", following the examples like meter, register etc. However, I can find very little examples of using this spelling in the literature. Should I use cadastre - the spelling which seemed to dominate worldwide?

Comment: The headword in Webster's 1864 dictionary is **cadaster**  and it is also supplied as **cadaster** (as a variant spelling) in Collins online when American English is selected. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cadaster  So to spell it **cadaster** would be no **disastre**.

Comment: It does seem to be very rare, doesn't it? http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46915519

Comment: Relying on a spelling used in an 1864 dictionary is to put yourself at the disposal of an outdated dictionary. Go to [one look dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=cadastre&ls=a&loc=home_ac_cadsasre), plug in both spellings, and see which spelling is used in most cases of American English. In the current Merriam Webster, you won't find [cadaster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/cadaster).

Comment: Which dictionaries did you check? What did you discover?

Comment: I can find both spellings in dictionaries. But Google finds only 342,000 results for cadaster and 81,700,000 results for cadastre (1 : 239). This is what bothers me.

Comment: I don't think this is a "basic question on spelling".  Both spellings exist, but the OP already knows this and has explained why they're confused.  Why did we close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both spellings are correct, ***[cadastre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cadastre%2Ccadaster&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccadastre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcadastre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCadastre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCADASTRE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccadaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcadaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCadaster%3B%2Cc0)*** is the more used both  in AmE and BrE, so you may probably opt for the more common spelling:

***[Cadastre or cadaster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cadastre)***:

> - an official register of the ownership, extent, and value of real property in a given area, used as a basis of taxation.

(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)